# For a folder, show Dates Last Modified of files next to cells hyperlinking to the files

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I have an Excel spreadsheet and use VBA to show a list of files in a specific folder. The VBA also creates hyperlinks for me. That is working fine.  However, it does not place the Dates Last Modified in the cells next to each hyperlink.

For example, if `TestFold.pdf` is in cell A1 - I want the date last modified of this file (hyperlink) in cell B1 (next to it).

My end goal is every time a new folder is added to the server location, I can simply run my VBA and get the list of all files in that folder as hyperlinks (which I have already done) and with their last modified date next to them.

My VBA for getting the folders and displaying as hyperlinks is as follows:

```
Sub Hyperlink()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim i As Integer


Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("S:\Promigen Orders")
i = 1

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

Range(Cells(i + 1, 1), Cells(i + 1, 1)).Select

ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:= _
    objFile.Path, _
    TextToDisplay:=objFile.Name
i = i + 1
Next objFile
End Sub
```

Can it be added to this VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `filedatetime` function is one you are looking for

**EDIT**

Yes, skkakkar's answer is even better, I edited my code with his suggestion :

```
Sub Hyperlink()
Dim objFSO As Object, objFolder As Object, objFile As Object
Dim i As Integer

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("S:\Promigen Orders")
i = 1

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

Range(Cells(i + 1, 1), Cells(i + 1, 1)).Select

ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:= _
objFile.Path, TextToDisplay:=objFile.Name

Range(Cells(i + 1, 2), Cells(i + 1, 2)) = objFile.DateLastModified
i = i + 1
Next objFile
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I am new to VBA. How do I add the filedatetime function to my above VBA code? So that it places the dates modified next to each hyperlink?

Comment: I just edited my answer, it will show dates as you requested

Comment: Wonderful! Worked perfectly! Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Just add one line in your code as shown below

```
  TextToDisplay:=objFile.Name
Range(Cells(i + 1, 2), Cells(i + 1, 2)).Value2 = Format(objFile.DateLastModified, "dd-mmm-yyyy")

i = i + 1
```